# Python JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter

Tags: python, json

This is the first time I am working with json files. I have a json file

```
{
"schema-map" : [
        {
        "src-file": "employee_master.xlsx",
        "dest-file": "employee_master.xlsx",
        "field-map" : {
            "user_id"  : "Unique ID",
            "employee_name" : "Name",
            "employee_address" : "Address for Communication",
            "pin_code" : "",
            "employee_code" : "Codes",
            "bank_account_no" : "bank_account_no",
            "telephone" : "",
            "email_id" : "email_id",
            "pan" : "PAN Card Num",
            "dependent_family_member" : ""
        }
]}
```

Now I am trying to get the data form this json using

```
with open('schema-map.json') as json_data:
d = json.load(json_data)
print(d)
```

I get the following error.`JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter`
I want to know If there is anything wrong with the json file, or the code could  be modified.

Comment: You are missing one curly bracket before the last `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're JSON file is missing a closing `}` bracket to close the `field-map` group.

```
{
"schema-map" : [
    {
        "src-file": "employee_master.xlsx",
        "dest-file": "employee_master.xlsx",
        "field-map" : {
            "user_id"  : "Unique ID",
            "employee_name" : "Name",
            "employee_address" : "Address for Communication",
            "pin_code" : "",
            "employee_code" : "Codes",
            "bank_account_no" : "bank_account_no",
            "telephone" : "",
            "email_id" : "email_id",
            "pan" : "PAN Card Num",
            "dependent_family_member" : ""
        }
    }
]}
```